# How to apply for a Schengen visa if I don't have payslips from the last 3 months?

Tags: visas, schengen, poland, proof-of-employment

I just started a LLC (limited liability company) and I'll be receiving my first pay slip next week, and I want to apply for a Schengen visa, can't I apply for the visa with 1 or 2 slips?

http://www.algier.msz.gov.pl/fr/service_consulaire/visas/.
You can load the English version as well

Comment: Do you have payslips from a previous job? Does your LLC have an ongoing contract with a company to provide your services?

Comment: Unfortunately, No and No. :(

Answer (score -4):

If you are in UK, then you can always call VFS and ask them, they might be able to answer your question.

Also if you don't want to take the risk of your visa being rejected, wait for three months and then apply for a Schengen Visa. If the visa is in business category then that is a different story.

Comment: -1 for an answer that is effectively “I don’t know, ask someone else or do something inconvenient to be safe”.